# Android LinearLayout and weights issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-layout-weight

I am having trouble with a LinearLayout and weights in Android. I want a horizontal LinearLayout to hold 2 vertical LinearLayouts separated by a single View with a 9 patch background to be the separator between the 2 vertical LinearLayouts.

Like this: (outer box is the outer LinearLayout and the middle double line is my 9 patch separator.)

```
----------------------------
|    one    ||    three    |
|    two    ||    four     |
----------------------------
```

What keeps happening is the first inner LinearLayout displays with minimal width to display its content (as if it's width is `wrap_content`), then the rest of the space is taken up by the separator view stretched to fill the rest of the outer LinearLayout. The 2nd inner LinearLayout is not displaying at all.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="one" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="two" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/divider_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="three" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="four" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I cannot figure out for the life of me why the middle View is taking up all of the space, leaving none for the second inner LinearLayout.

I can get it to work if I specify a specific px or dp width for the 9-patch view, but I really want it to work without having to specify this width. That way if I decide to change my 9-patch drawable, I won't have to manually update the width.

Comment: have u got the solution or still the same issue

Comment: Have you tried giving the divider view an acutual width? Say 10dp or something?

Comment: Yes. giving the divider an actual width solves the issue but I am looking for a solution that does not involve this. See my update to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This layout

**Updated Layout**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="one" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="two" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="three" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="four" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This does work (specifying a specific layout_width), but I would rather not have to specify this width in case I decide to use a different drawable 9-patch as my divider becuase then I would have to manually update this width accoridngly. I've updated this in my original question.

Comment: I will mark this as the solution because this is what I went with. Couldn't figure out a nicer way to do it. Note that I did not have to explicitly set the height of the divider, I was able to leave it at match_parent. Also, I used a dimen for the layout_width where I had an exact pixel value for the width of the divider since I actually have different image assets for this divider for different screen resolutions (and also different pixel values for this dimen for the different screen resolutions as well).

Answer (score 0):

Updtae here and try

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/divider_vertical"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the `weightSum="2"` from parent LinearLayout.
- Remove the `android:layout_weight="0"` from 9 patch view

Comment: I know adding weightSum and android:layout_weight="0" were unnecessary, but removing them does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

How big is your 9 patch? the stretchable regions of a 9 patch are not shrinkable - the width of the asset's file will determine the minimum space it will try to take in your LinearLayout.

Comment: The 9 patch is only 5 px by 3px. I have the 9 patch set up properly with lines on all 4 edges and in the proper locations

Answer (score 0):

Set layout weights as below

keep in mind the weightSum of the parent by default it is set to the children's layout_weight sum

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="3" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="one" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="two" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/divider_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="3" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="three" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="four" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

certainly you can experiment with values for weigths